# How does one print the elements of a hash in the order they were added to the hash

Tags: perl, hash

How does one print the key/value pairs of a hash in the order they were added to the hash.

For example:

```
%hash = ("a", "1", "b", "2", "c", "3");
while (($key, $value) = each %hash) {
   print "$key", "$value\n";
}
```

The above results in the following:

```
c3
a1
b2
```

I am looking for a way to print the following:

```
a1
b2
c3
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you don't want to use any of the mentioned modules (Tie::IxHash and Tie::Hash::Indexed), and since hashes are *[unordered collections](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html)* (as said before), you have to store this information while inserting the values:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %hash;
my %index; #keep track of the insertion order
my $i=0;
for (["a","1"], ["b","2"], ["c","3"]) { #caveat: you can't insert values in your hash as you did before in one line
    $index{$_->[0]}=$i++;
    $hash{$_->[0]}=$_->[1];
}

for (sort {$index{$a}<=>$index{$b}} keys %hash) {  #caveat: you can't use while anymore since you need to sort
   print "$_$hash{$_}\n";
}
```

This will print:

```
a1
b2
c3
```

Answer (score 8):

> How do you print the key/value pairs of a hash, in the order they appear in the hash.

The code you used does exactly that. c3, a1, b2 is the order in which the elements appear in the [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) at that time.

What you actually want to do with print them in the order they were inserted. For that, you'll need to keep track of the order in which elements were inserted, or you'll have to use something other than a hash, such as aformentioned [Tie::IxHash](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie::IxHash) and [Tie::Hash::Indexed](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Tie::Hash::Indexed).

Comment: which is preferred nowadays?

Comment: @mpapec, I've never had a need for either. I was always able to make due with an array or an array+hash combo.

Answer (score 5):

A hash is not ordered. You need to choose another data structure.

Comment: Did not know this, thanks. Will have to find a workaround then :)

Answer (score 5):

You'll need `Tie::IxHash` module for ordered hashes,

```
use Tie::IxHash;

tie(my %hash, 'Tie::IxHash');
%hash = ("a", "1", "b", "2", "c", "3");

while (my ($key, $value) = each %hash) {
  print "$key", "$value\n";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

A hash is generally unordered. You can instead use an ordered hash. Try [Tie::Hash::Indexed](http://search.cpan.org/~mhx/Tie-Hash-Indexed-0.05/lib/Tie/Hash/Indexed.pm) from CPAN.

From the documentation:

```
  use Tie::Hash::Indexed;

  tie my %hash, 'Tie::Hash::Indexed';

  %hash = ( I => 1, n => 2, d => 3, e => 4 );
  $hash{x} = 5;

  print keys %hash, "\n";    # prints 'Index'
  print values %hash, "\n";  # prints '12345'
```

Comment: This did work, however, I'm trying not to include modules.
Will have to find another way to go about with this.
Thanks for the help though :)